# How to change MySQL query search from 0 to 1 using checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change my query fetch from showing items with a 0 to 1 and back again using a checkbox.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT rowNum, DeviceID, IP, MAC, ServiceT, Brand, Model, Location, Retired FROM equipement";
if ($_POST['box-retired'] == 'y')
  {$query .= " WHERE Retired = '0'";}
else
  {$query .= " WHERE Retired = '1'";}
$response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($response)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))
    {
      echo '<table><tr>
        <td align="left">'.$row['DeviceID'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['IP'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['MAC'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['ServiceT'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['Brand'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['Model'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['Location'].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row['Retired'].'</td>
        <td><a href="editGUIinfo.php?edit_id='.$row['rowNum'].'">
            <button type="button"> Edit</button></a>
        </td>
            </tr></table>';
    }
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="box-retired" id="box-retired" value="n"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box-retired" id="box-retired" value="y">
        <b>Retired</b>
    </input>
```

The result I am looking for is when the checkbox is checked it changes my $query "WHERE Retired = 0" to "WHERE Retired = 1" and back again when unchecked. I included some pictures of what I am talking about. Hope it helps.

[Before the query fetch changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8vgL.png)

[after the query fetch changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg7HP.png)

Comment: You can't have two inputs with the same name. Instead, remove the hidden, and check for `!empty($_POST['box-retired'])`. Empty is unchecked, true is checked.

Comment: Remember, checkboxes are NOT sent to the PHP if they are not checked, so if its not checked you have to ask, does that field exists in the $_POST array and if not it was not checked

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices :

1. Easiest : Sorting with JavaScript

Get all rows no matter equipment is retired or not.
Show the according results depending on which box is checked.

2. Cleanest : Implementing AJAX

Make an ajax call to get the right rows, once again depending on which box is checked.

In both case, you have to refresh tables when box status changes which seems logic.